# Why can non-extern be in .h files in C/C++?

Tags: c, symbols, header-files

Take [this file](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/module.h) as example,there are many non-extern structures like:

```
struct list_head source_list;
```

How can it work when this header file is included by more than one compile units?

There should be error reporting that the same symbol is defined twice,right?

Comment: "compile unit" is usually termed a "translation unit".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically there should, but that usage has been around for years and is impossible to eradicate (it's been tried; every so often some vendor decides to make it an error, and reverts after the first hundred or so bug reports).  Pedantically, the `.h` file should declare it `extern` and *one* `.c`/`.cpp` file should define it.

Briefly, when you don't specify the linkage (`static`, `extern`, etc.) of a top level variable, it's declared as "common".  At link time, if all references to that variable are the same size (and type, when available) then it is allocated once and all references are made to point to it.  If the linker finds different sizes / types / linkages for the same variable, it throws an error.

EDIT:  this is clearly confounding people.  Here:

```
jinx:1714 Z$ cat foo.h
int foo;
extern void bar();
jinx:1715 Z$ cat foo.c
#include "foo.h"

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  bar();
  return 0;
}
jinx:1716 Z$ cat bar.c
#include "foo.h"

void
bar(void)
{
  return;
}
jinx:1717 Z$ gcc -Wall foo.c bar.c -o foo
jinx:1718 Z$ ./foo
jinx:1719 Z$ _
```

Note the complete lack of errors about `int foo` being multiply defined.  *This* is what I've been trying to say.

Comment: Are you saying that `struct list_head source_list;` in `module.h` is a definition of a variable?

Comment: @ssmir:  It's a declaration, not a definition (unless it's initialized, as noted elsepage).  It's implicitly marked as "common", so the linker will (as long as all declarations are compatible with each other) define it itself.

Comment: Ok, so is it a declaration of a global variable?

Comment: @ssmir: Effectively.  I'm trying to draw the distinction that a proper declaration of a global variable happens once, but for historical reasons you can declare it multiple times and as long as they're all compatible the linker will make it work.  It's rather messy and confusing (and I recall the GNU `binutils` folks complaining about the work needed to support it back when), which is why every so often someone tries to kill it off.

Comment: Thanks, the fact that compilers accept such multiple declarations is quite interesting. However `struct list_head source_list;`'s in `module.h` are not global variable declarations because they happen inside other structures (namely `module_use` and `module`).

Comment: What if `struct list_head source_list;` is not inside any structure?It will be a definition and so the header file can't be included twice,right?

Comment: @compile-fan If it would be outside then it would be a tentative definition.

Comment: @compile-fan: See typescript added to reply.  It really isn't an error.

Comment: @geekosaur, @compile-fan, sorry to say but your answer is simply incorrect. It is a "tentative definition" as I have stated in my answer, and nothing else. It is completely legal in C and you can't eradicate something that is covered by the standard. And nowhere in the C standard there is the idea of "common" variables or such a thing.

Comment: @Jens, the notion of "common" is indeed not part of the C standard:  it's part of the *linker*.  The standard's "tentative" was a late acknowledgement that conventional usage wasn't going to go away, and was avoiding any mention of implementation — but most linkers go the way of "common" because it's the easiest way to do it *and* the behavior of traditional Unix `ld`.

Comment: @Jens Gustedt, so you mean `int foo;` in `foo.h` is file scope,how do you prove this ?

Comment: @compile-fan, what do you mean by prove? `int foo;` is at global scope if it is not at function scope, that is if it is not inside a function definition. If this originates from including another file is completely irrelevant. That's it, there are no other cases.

Comment: @compile-fan: it's just differing terminology. After several attempts (*not* by the ANSI committee) to eradicate the usage, the standard was amended to bless it with terminology that didn't reference mechanism.   But the easiest mechanism is the same one used to support FORTRAN `COMMON` blocks (hence the name).  Admittedly it would be odd for the ANSI C standard to reference the FORTRAN standard :)

Answer (score 1):

This `struct list_head source_list;` fields are declared inside other structures so they are not symbols.

Declarations of other (top level) structures have distinct names so it's ok too.

**edit**

Note that all *variables* it this header are really marked with `extern`.

Answer (score 1):

The term for this is "tentative definition":

> A declaration of an identifier for an
>   object that has file scope without an
>   initializer, and    without a
>   storage-class specifier or with the
>   storage-class specifier static,
>   constitutes a
>         tentative definition. If a translation unit contains one or more
>   tentative definitions for an
>            identifier, and the translation unit contains no external
>   definition for that identifier, then
>                 the behavior is exactly as if the translation unit contains a
>   file scope declaration of that
>                  identifier, with the composite type as of the end of the
>   translation unit, with an initializer
>                   equal to 0.

So this is well defined in C (but often frowned upon).

Comment: @compile-fan Declaration in your question does not declare any kind of variable it just declares a field of a structure. Furthermore the structure inside which it's declared doesn't produce a symbol. It's not a tentative definition too.

Comment: @compile-fan, yes it can. Look, it says: `one or more tentative definitions for an identifier`.

Comment: @ssmir, you are right the examples that are pointed to in the question are as you have given in your answer (the +1 is from me :). But as is it presented in the question itself, it is a tentative definition.

Comment: Thanks :) It seems that he really meant a tentative definition.

Answer (score 0):

There should be an `extern` indeed. However, there's no explicit *definition* of that variable, so the compiler marks it as extern for you.

You would get a linker error if you had

```
struct list_head source_list = { 0 };
```

...since this *does* define the symbol once per translation unit (and hence the linker complains).

Comment: This is a definition, a so-called tentative one.