# Can anyone explain this portion of the C++0x draft standard?

Tags: c++, c++11, linkage

From ISO Standard Draft: §`3.0/9`:

n3234 says:

> A name used in more than one translation unit can potentially refer to the
>         same entity in these translationunits depending on the linkage (3.5) of the
>         name specified in each translation unit.

Can anyone explain this point with an example, please?

What is that statement actually saying?  Can any one prove this point in terms of a program?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure!  What this is saying is that if you have multiple source files (translation units) that both use some name (for example, the name of a variable, class or function), then it's possible that those different files are talking about the same variable, class, or function, assuming that that entity was declared in a way that makes it visible across different files (that is, depending on its linkage).

For example, if I have this file:

A.cpp:

```
int globalInt;

int main() {
     globalInt = 137;
}
```

And this one here:

B.cpp:

```
extern int globalInt;

void foo() {
    globalInt = 42;
}
```

Then in both files, the name `globalInt` refers to the global `int` variable `globalInt` defined in A.cpp.  That's all that this point is saying.

Note, however, that if I declare `globalInt` without external linkage, then the two files will be talking about different variables.  For example, in this case:

C.cpp:

```
static int globalInt;

int main() {
     globalInt = 137;
}
```

D.cpp:

```
static int globalInt;

void foo() {
    globalInt = 42;
}
```

Now the `globalInt` variable referenced in C.cpp is *not* the same as the one in D.cpp, even though they have the same name.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Note that if only one file declares it `static`, it's still separate, although a third file `E.cpp` can still get at the one that wasn't declared `static`.

Comment: @geekosaur: To add to this, if you have more then one declared as neither `static` nor `extern`, the linker will output an error about and object being already defined. So you can always only have one `int globalInt` defined, all other ones have to be either `extern` (then they refer to the original one) or `static` (then they shadow the original one and are only valid within the same translation unit).

Comment: @Mephane: Not quite; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404876/why-can-non-extern-be-in-h-files-in-c-c

Comment: @geekosaur: That other question is only tagged as C, this one here as C++. Are you sure what is said there also applies to C++?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, standards... let's obfuscate the obvious.

It's saying that, if you use a global variable with the same name in two different source files, they will be the same variable if they are `extern` or don't specify at all, but if any of them are declared `static` then those will be completely independent because they're only visible in that source file.

```
int a;        // can be seen in other files; this may be duplicated in multiple source files
static int b; // can only be used in this file
extern int c; // explicitly using a visible variable "c" defined in another file
```

("Linkage" is the `static`/`extern`/default global, or `auto` which is almost never mentioned since it means "allocated on the stack", which is the default for variables declared inside a function and obviously not meaningful for a declaration outside a function.  "Translation unit" is a common way for standards to avoid mentioning "files".)